# How to Fix text positioning during recreation of pdf

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdfdocument

[input pdf image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m09NJ.jpg) first one is input and this is output pdf pic [output pdf image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeLkb.jpg)I need help regarding text positioning during recreation of pdf. I have extracted all text using text stripper and able to draw on new pdf with correct font and font size. But Not able to draw text at its correct position.

//this is how I extracting TextPosition data

```
protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
         textPositionPDGraphicsStatesMap.put(text, getGraphicsState());
         PDGraphicsState state = getGraphicsState();
         PDTextState textState = state.getTextState();
         float fontSize = textState.getFontSize();
         float horizontalScaling = textState.getHorizontalScaling() / 100f;
         float charSpacing = textState.getCharacterSpacing();

         // put the text state parameters into matrix form
         Matrix parameters = new Matrix(
                    fontSize * horizontalScaling, 0, // 0
                    0, fontSize,                     // 0
                    0, textState.getRise());         // 1
        
        // text rendering matrix (text space -> device space)
        Matrix ctm = state.getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
        Matrix textRenderingMatrix = parameters.multiply(text.getTextMatrix()).multiply(ctm);
        
        TextPositionsInfo txtInfo = new TextPositionsInfo();
        txtInfo.xDir = text.getXDirAdj();
        txtInfo.yDir = text.getYDirAdj();
        txtInfo.x =  textRenderingMatrix.getTranslateX();
        txtInfo.y = textRenderingMatrix.getTranslateY();
        txtInfo.textMatrix = textRenderingMatrix;
        txtInfo.height= text.getHeightDir();
        txtInfo.width = text.getWidthDirAdj(); 
        txtInfo.unicode = text.getUnicode();
        txtInfo.fontName = text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().getFontName();
        txtInfo.fontSize = getActualFontSize(text, getGraphicsState());
        pdfGraphicContent.textPositions.add(txtInfo);
        
    }
```

//here I am placing each char and set to content stream

```
private void addTextCharByChar(String string, List<TextPositionsInfo> textinfoList, TextBBoxinfo textBBoxinfo,PDPage page) throws IOException {

         PDResources res = page.getResources();
        currentContentStream.beginText(); 
        if (textBBoxinfo._ElementType.toLowerCase().equals("h2")) {
            beginMarkedConent(COSName.P);
            for(TextPositionsInfo textInfo : textinfoList) {
                PDFont font = getFont(res, textInfo.fontName);
                currentContentStream.setFont(font, textInfo.fontSize);
                Matrix _tm = textInfo.textMatrix;
                currentContentStream.newLineAtOffset(_tm.getTranslateX(), _tm.getTranslateY());
                currentContentStream.setTextMatrix(_tm);
                currentContentStream.showText(textInfo.unicode);
            }
            currentContentStream.endMarkedContent();
            addContentToCurrentSection(COSName.P, StandardStructureTypes.H2);
            
        }else if (textBBoxinfo._ElementType.toLowerCase().equals("h1")) {
            beginMarkedConent(COSName.P);
            for(TextPositionsInfo textInfo : textinfoList) {
                PDFont font = getFont(res, textInfo.fontName);
                currentContentStream.setFont(font, textInfo.fontSize);
                currentContentStream.newLineAtOffset(textInfo.textMatrix.getTranslateX(), 
              textInfo.textMatrix.getTranslateY());
               currentContentStream.setTextMatrix(textInfo.textMatrix);
                currentContentStream.showText(textInfo.unicode);
            }
            currentContentStream.endMarkedContent();
            addContentToCurrentSection(COSName.P, StandardStructureTypes.H1);
            
        }
        currentContentStream.endText();
        }
    }
```

Comment: And the problem is...? (Please indicate how the result deviates from the expectation, and whether that happens for all PDFs or just for some.)

Comment: hi @mkl please look into above image . I have added for your reference . 

input pdf image description here  is input document and  output pdf image description here  is output pdf link.  Also all text is not coming. So please help me how to fix text positioning issues specially. Thanks in advance

Comment: hi @KJ actually I want to get exact x and y coordinate of each text and then draw it on pdf during recreation. Same thing I am doing in above code but failed to do so. So suggest me how to calculate each char x and y. that is my main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is an error in the code you show. But the as I couldn't reproduce the error as it shows in your screenshots, I assume that there is another error somewhere in the code you don't show.**

### In detail

Unfortunately you neither provided self-contained code nor your example PDF. To check it, therefore, I had to change the code a bit to make it runnable. Furthermore, I had to select a test document of my own; I actually found one looking very much like your screenshot.

#### The error

In `processTextPosition` you try to calculate the text rendering matrix like this:

```java
 PDGraphicsState state = getGraphicsState();
 PDTextState textState = state.getTextState();
 float fontSize = textState.getFontSize();
 float horizontalScaling = textState.getHorizontalScaling() / 100f;
 float charSpacing = textState.getCharacterSpacing();

 // put the text state parameters into matrix form
 Matrix parameters = new Matrix(
            fontSize * horizontalScaling, 0, // 0
            0, fontSize,                     // 0
            0, textState.getRise());         // 1

// text rendering matrix (text space -> device space)
Matrix ctm = state.getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
Matrix textRenderingMatrix = parameters.multiply(text.getTextMatrix()).multiply(ctm);
```

This looks like the right way to calculate the text rendering matrix from the available data. EXCEPT if you read the documentation of the `TextPosition.getTextMatrix` method:

```java
/**
 * The matrix containing the starting text position and scaling. Despite the name, it is not the
 * text matrix set by the "Tm" operator, it is really the effective text rendering matrix (which
 * is dependent on the current transformation matrix (set by the "cm" operator), the text matrix
 * (set by the "Tm" operator), the font size (set by the "Tf" operator) and the page cropbox).
 *
 * @return The Matrix containing the starting text position
 */
public Matrix getTextMatrix()
```

Thus, `text.getTextMatrix()` already is the matrix you want to calculate here. So you can either replace the whole block above by

```java
Matrix textRenderingMatrix = text.getTextMatrix();
```

or (if you really want to calculate the text rendering matrix yourself) use `state.getTextMatrix()` instead of `text.getTextMatrix()` in that block.

#### The changed code

I changed your `processTextPosition` override to:

```java
            protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
//                textPositionPDGraphicsStatesMap.put(text, getGraphicsState());
                PDGraphicsState state = getGraphicsState();
                PDTextState textState = state.getTextState();
                float fontSize = textState.getFontSize();
                float horizontalScaling = textState.getHorizontalScaling() / 100f;
                float charSpacing = textState.getCharacterSpacing();

                // put the text state parameters into matrix form
                Matrix parameters = new Matrix(
                           fontSize * horizontalScaling, 0, // 0
                           0, fontSize,                     // 0
                           0, textState.getRise());         // 1
               
               // text rendering matrix (text space -> device space)
               Matrix ctm = state.getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
               Matrix textRenderingMatrix = parameters.multiply(/*text*/state.getTextMatrix()).multiply(ctm);
               
               TextPositionsInfo txtInfo = new TextPositionsInfo();
               txtInfo.xDir = text.getXDirAdj();
               txtInfo.yDir = text.getYDirAdj();
               txtInfo.x =  textRenderingMatrix.getTranslateX();
               txtInfo.y = textRenderingMatrix.getTranslateY();
               txtInfo.textMatrix = textRenderingMatrix;
               txtInfo.height= text.getHeightDir();
               txtInfo.width = text.getWidthDirAdj(); 
               txtInfo.unicode = text.getUnicode();
               txtInfo.fontName = text.getFont().getFontDescriptor().getFontName();
               txtInfo.fontSize = getActualFontSize(text, getGraphicsState());
               /*pdfGraphicContent.*/textPositions.add(txtInfo);

// font provisioning not provided by OP. Simple stub.
targetPage.getResources().put(COSName.getPDFName(txtInfo.fontName), text.getFont());
            }

            // not provided by OP. Simple stub
            private float getActualFontSize(TextPosition text, PDGraphicsState graphicsState) {
                return text.getFontSize();
            }
```

*([CopyFormattedPageText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox3/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox3/content/CopyFormattedPageText.java) method `copyTextLikeNitishKumar`)*

The main change here is that I fixed the error (see above) and added the font to the target page resources; as you do not show how you fill the target page resources and match fonts with names, this was the easiest way to improvise this. Beware, this is not a good way to improvise this, this might lose quite some font information...

I then changed your `addTextCharByChar` to:

```java
    private void addTextCharByChar(/*String string,*/ List<TextPositionsInfo> textinfoList, /*TextBBoxinfo textBBoxinfo,*/ PDPage page, PDPageContentStream currentContentStream) throws IOException {
        PDResources res = page.getResources();

        currentContentStream.beginText(); 
//        if (textBBoxinfo._ElementType.toLowerCase().equals("h2")) {
            currentContentStream.beginMarkedContent(COSName.P);
            for(TextPositionsInfo textInfo : textinfoList) {
                PDFont font = getFont(res, textInfo.fontName);
                currentContentStream.setFont(font, /*textInfo.fontSize*/1);
                Matrix _tm = textInfo.textMatrix;
                currentContentStream.newLineAtOffset(_tm.getTranslateX(), _tm.getTranslateY());
                currentContentStream.setTextMatrix(_tm);
                currentContentStream.showText(textInfo.unicode);
            }
            currentContentStream.endMarkedContent();
//            addContentToCurrentSection(COSName.P, StandardStructureTypes.H2);
//        } else if (textBBoxinfo._ElementType.toLowerCase().equals("h1")) {
//            beginMarkedConent(COSName.P);
//            for(TextPositionsInfo textInfo : textinfoList) {
//                PDFont font = getFont(res, textInfo.fontName);
//                currentContentStream.setFont(font, textInfo.fontSize);
//                currentContentStream.newLineAtOffset(textInfo.textMatrix.getTranslateX(), textInfo.textMatrix.getTranslateY());
//                currentContentStream.setTextMatrix(textInfo.textMatrix);
//                currentContentStream.showText(textInfo.unicode);
//            }
//            currentContentStream.endMarkedContent();
//            addContentToCurrentSection(COSName.P, StandardStructureTypes.H1);
//        }
        currentContentStream.endText();
    }

    // not provided by OP. Simple stub
    private PDFont getFont(PDResources res, String fontName) throws IOException {
        return res.getFont(COSName.getPDFName(fontName));
    }
```

The main change here is dropping code paths that depend on extra information you didn't share, like `textBBoxinfo`. Furthermore, I use `1` as font size in the `currentContentStream.setFont` because you thereafter set the text matrix to the original text rendering matrix which already contains a scaling by the text font size.

#### The result

Running the code for [this file](https://www.princexml.com/howcome/2016/samples/invoice/index.pdf) (which looks very much like your screenshot) results in:

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| [image: input] | [image: output] |

So it looks like the code you shared works after fixing the text rendering matrix and font size.

#### Possible additional issues

The output you showed a screenshot of does not match the identified error. The error usually would print much too large letters, not a few letters at the correct size and dropping the others.

Thus, there appear to be other errors in the code you don't show. I can only guess their causes. My guesses would be:

- The `textBBoxinfo._ElementType` is only "H1" or "H2" for a few letters, the ones you see in your output. As there is no code path for drawing text with other element type values, most of the letters aren't drawn at all.
- Your font handling is erroneous and your `getFont` only returns a useful font for the letters you see in your output.
- Your `getActualFontSize` returns a sensible size only for a few letters, the ones you see in the output. The other letters are too small or not drawn at all in the output.

Comment: Matrix textRenderingMatrix = text.getTextMatrix(); this way I tried and it worked for me. Thanks a lot @mkl

Comment: Hi @mkl for above and some simple document it worked. But when I tested for some complex document getting following error. So what should be the best approach so that it works for all documents having multiple pages.

Comment: "Message":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+007D (}) in font MOFVKK+Wingdings-Regular at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.encode(PDCIDFontType2.java:361) at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.encode(PDType0Font.java:415) at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:332) at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showTextInternal(PDPageContentStream.java:514) at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showText(PDPageContentStream.java:476)

Comment: Without the document in question I cannot say for sure but the font in question does not seem to support text extraction, at least not roundtrip-wise (character-code -> Unicode -> character code).

Comment: Hi @mkl after updating pdfbox 2.0.21 to 2.0.23 , it is working fine . Because in previous version all encoding char is not supporting .

Comment: Great! It's (nearly) always a good idea to first update one's dependencies. Beware, though, 2.0.30 has been released last November...

Comment: "Message":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+25CF ('H18533') is not available in this font's encoding: built-in (Type 1) with differences at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1CFont.encode(PDType1CFont.java:346) at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:337) at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showTextInternal(PDPageContentStream.java:514) at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showText(PDPageContentStream.java:476)

Comment: hi @mkl giving same error for different document. Any permanent solution for this. I had updated to 2.0.30 version of pdfbox

Comment: Without the document in question I cannot say for sure but the font in question does not seem to support text extraction, at least not roundtrip-wise (character-code -> Unicode -> character code).